At least one element of a list and not all element of a list must match for a many to many relationship query in django
Here I have a list of place and tags for a reservation:
And I would like a query where at least one of the list of places and at least one of the tags need to match the query slot, and not all places and not all tags need to match for the slot reservation.
Example:
Here is the full list of places and tags:
Places = [1p,2p,3p,4p,5p,6p]
tags = [3,t,4t,5t,6t,7t,8t]

Here are the lists that I pass to my query:
Places = [2p,3p,4p]
tags = [5t,6t,7t]

I want slots with for example: 2p and 3p not 4p and 6t only.
I want slot with any combination of places in the list and any combination of tags in the list.
Here is my solution:
tags = Tag.objects.filter(name__in=tags)
print("tags", tags)
places = PartnerPlace.objects.filter(zip_code__in=cps)
print("places", places)
#slots is a queryset
slots = Slot.objects.filter()
for place in places:
    for tag in tags:
        slots = slots | Slot.objects.filter(
            tag=tag,
            place=place,
        )

It works but I think it's not elegant nor optimal if anyone have a better solution.
Regards

If i correct understand you need all Slots, where zip_code OR tag_name pass to your query.
slots = Slot.objects.filter(Q(tag__name__in=tags) | Q(place__zip_code__in=cps))

I concatenare Q object in .filter instead of concatenate results.
More about Q here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects
After you change the Question and if i correct understand it and the loop in question - you need all Slots, where zip_code in cps AND tag_name in tags.
slots = Slot.objects.filter(Q(tag__name__in=tags) & Q(place__zip_code__in=cps))

This queryset give you ALL slots, which you collect in your loop -

Slot.objects.filter(tag=tag, place=place)


i've edited my question

are you check queryset from answer? This queryset give you Slots with any tag from tags OR  Slots with any place from places. For Slots with any tag from tags AND Slots with any place from places in the same time simply change OR to AND.
